# Creating Multiple TOC for my ROBOHELP

Tags: robohelp, help-authoring

I am creating a robo help for my project and want to create a role based robo help i.e some pages will be hidden for some roles. For that I created multiple Table Of Contents. My question is how to call multiple TOC from my Java project depending on the roles.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple TOCs in RoboHelp, but you can only output one at a time.  In other words, each compiled Help can only contain one TOC.  But you can create multiple Helps, each with different TOCs and then you just have to tell your Java code which Help you want to open.

1. Create one **Single Source Layout** for each TOC you want to produce.
2. Specify which TOC you want to use in each **Single Source Layout** (**Single Source Layout** >> **Content** settings).
3. Generate each **Single Source Layout** to different folders (**Single Source Layout** >> **General** >> **Output Location** settings).
4. Tell Java which Help to launch based on your own critera.